# Basis function of $\Gamma_2$ irrep of point group $T_d$?

Tags: angular-momentum, group-theory, crystals

From *Properties of the Thirty-Two Point Groups (Koster, et. al.)*, the basis function of the $\Gamma_2$ irrep of the point group $T_d$ is $l_xl_yl_z$, where $l$ is the angular momentum operator. However, from *Cho, K.: Phys. Rev. B 14, 4463 (1976)*, the basis function used for $\Gamma_2$ is $xl_x+yl_y+zl_z$. I am confused with the latter one because it seems to be zero: $$xl_x+yl_y+zl_z=x(yp_z-zp_y)+y(zp_x-xp_z)+z(xp_y-yp_x)=0$$ Any idea on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem by referring to the multiplication table of the $T_d$ point group: $$\Gamma_4\otimes\Gamma_5=\Gamma_2\oplus\Gamma_3\oplus\Gamma_4\oplus\Gamma_5$$ The basis functions of $\Gamma_4$ and $\Gamma_5$ are $[l_x,l_y,l_z]$ and $[x,y,z]$, respectively. Then using the coupling coefficients table, the product basis functions of $\Gamma_2$ is $1/\sqrt 3(xl_x+yl_y+zl_z)$.